# Condition on Nth character of string in a Mth column in bash

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a sample

```
$ cat c.csv
a,1234543,c
b,1231456,d
c,1230654,e
```

I need to grep only numbers where 4th character of 2nd column but not be 0 or 1

Output must be

```
a,1234543,c
```

I know this only

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~/^[2-9]/' c.csv
```

Is it possible to put a condition on 4th character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} substr($2,4,1)!=0 && substr($2,4,1)!=1' Input_file
```

OR as per Ed site's suggestion:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} substr($2,4,1)!~[01]' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=","                                     ##Setting field separator as comma here.
}                                            ##Closing BLOCK for this program BEGIN section.
substr($2,4,1)!=0 && substr($2,4,1)!=1       ##Checking conditions if 4th character of current line is NOT 0 and 1 then print the current line.
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed or grep):

```
grep -vE '^([^,]*,){1}[^,]{3}[01]' file
```

or:

```
sed -E '/^([^,]*,){1}[^,]{3}[01]/d' file
```

Replace the `1` for the m'th-1 column and the `3` for the n'th-1 character in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Grep is the answer.
But here is another way using array and variable substitution

```
test=( $(cat c.csv) ) # load c.csv data to an array
echo ${test[@]//*,???[0-1]*/} # print all items from an array,
# but remove the ones that correspond to this regex *,???[0-1]*
# so 'b,1231456,d' and 'c,1230654,e' from example will be removed
# and only 'a,1234543,c' will be printed
```

Comment: Is it a bashism? May I ask for a short description?

Comment: @d.c. yep, updated my answer

Comment: THX, unlinke on unix.stack... I have no right to moderate, so this was an easiest way to improve the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this with awk. the most literal form would be:

- 4th character of 2nd column is not 0 or 1

  ```
  $ awk -F, '($2 !~ /^...[01]/)' file
  $ awk -F, '($2 ~ /^...[^01]/)' file
  ```

  These will also match a line `a,abcdefg,b`
- 2nd column is an integer and 4th character is not 0 or 1

  ```
  $ awk -F, '($2+0==$2) && ($2!~[.]) && ($2 !~ /^...[01]/)'
  $ awk -F, '($2 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][^01][0-9]*$/)'
  ```